# What is the idiomatic way to implement `IntoIterator` when some items need to be substituted?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a custom collection like this:

```rust
struct VecChoice<T> {
    v1: Vec<T>,
    v2: Vec<T>,
    use_v1: Vec<bool>,
}
```

in the impl I can iterate this collection like this:

```rust
fn foo(&self, ...) {
    let item_refs: Vec<_> = (0..self.v1.len()).map(|i| {
        if self.use_v1[i] {
            &self.v1[i]
        } else {
            &self.v2[i]
        }
    });
    // ... do whatever I want with chosen references
}
```

However, I am failing to make it iterable:

```rust
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a VecChoice<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    // this fails because the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn FnMut(usize) -> Self::Item + 'static)`
    type IntoIter = Map<usize, dyn FnMut(usize) -> Self::Item>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        (0..self.v1.len()).map(|i| {
            if self.use_v1[i] {
                &self.v1[i]
            } else {
                &self.v2[i]
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I could probably collect results into a `Vec<&T>` as above, then use its `into_iter`, but I suspect there should be a way to do it without constructing intermediate `Vec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure that you have passed to `map` actually does have a size. The problem though is that this type isn't nameable. You've tried to solve that with `dyn`, which isn't quite the right solution because the closure *is* sized but `dyn` makes it so that it isn't. `dyn` would be appropriate if there were different possible sizes, but then you'd have to put it behind a pointer of some kind so that the `IntoIter` type is `Sized`.

This is one of those cases where it is probably better to implement the `Iterator` manually, rather than using combinators.

```
struct VecChoiceIter<'a, T> {
    index: usize,
    vec_choice: &'a VecChoice<T>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for VecChoiceIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index == self.vec_choice.v1.len() {
            None
        } else {
            let i = self.index;
            self.index += 1;
            let use_v1 = self.vec_choice.use_v1[i];
            if use_v1 {
                Some(&self.vec_choice.v1[i])
            } else {
                Some(&self.vec_choice.v2[i])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you a `Sized` and nameable type that you can use for the `IntoIterator` implementation:

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a VecChoice<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = VecChoiceIter<'a, T>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        VecChoiceIter { index: 0, vec_choice: self }
    }
}
```

---

There are some interesting RFCs in progress that could make this work more like how you originally wanted. In particular [RFC-2515](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2515-type_alias_impl_trait.md). This would let you write your `IntoIterator` implementation as you originally tried, but without having to name the type ([playground - nightly](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d0fbf096aede4597c47628b4cc81018f)):

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a VecChoice<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    // This is an "existential" type. That is, tell the compiler that there is 
    // exactly one possibility for what this type can be, which it can infer 
    // from the usage.
    type IntoIter = impl Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        (0..self.v1.len()).map(move |i| {
            if self.use_v1[i] {
                &self.v1[i]
            } else {
                &self.v2[i]
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's often very tempting to try to make an iterator out of a pre-made collection, but unfortunately this tends to run into a practical problem a lot of the time: you need some way to store an offset into that collection, so you serve the right chunk of data out of it when `next` is called.  Consequently, you almost always need to provide some custom iterator type.

In this case, you can do so like this:

```
struct VecChoice<T> {
    v1: Vec<T>,
    v2: Vec<T>,
    use_v1: Vec<bool>,
}

struct VecChoiceIter<'a, T> {
    off: usize,
    collection: &'a VecChoice<T>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for VecChoiceIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let off = self.off;
        self.off += 1;
        if *self.collection.use_v1.get(off)? {
            self.collection.v1.get(off)
        } else {
            self.collection.v2.get(off)
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a VecChoice<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    type IntoIter = VecChoiceIter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        VecChoiceIter {
            off: 0,
            collection: self,
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in this case, I've switched `use_v1` to a `Vec<bool>`, because this is not C and only booleans can be used in conditionals.

You could also do the conversion up front and store it in its own `Vec`, but in my experience people don't expect creating an iterator, whether by calling `iter` or `into_iter`, to be expensive.  Iterators are pretty fundamental in Rust, and as a consequence it's very common for folks to create lots of them, often implicitly, and making those functions be expensive would be undesirable in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most simple way is to use `.zip()` and return an opaque `impl Iterator` from a method on the type (so you don't have to write out the actual type):

```
struct VecChoice<T> {
    v1: Vec<T>,
    v2: Vec<T>,
    use_v1: Vec<bool>,
}

impl<T> VecChoice<T> {
    fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
        self.v1
            .iter()
            .zip(self.v2.iter())
            .zip(self.use_v1.iter())
            .map(|((v1, v2), use_v1)| if use_v1 { v1 } else { v2 })
    }
}
```

This will iterate over all three `Vec` (actually the shortest of them) and return either from `v1` or `v2`.

Notice that I switched `use_v1` from a `Vec<T>` to a `Vec<bool>`, which seems to be what you have, given the way you use it.